# Radiative Energy in a Gravity Well

Tags: general-relativity, energy, gravity

It has been hypothesized that in the very far future, most or all matter will have decayed into radiation.

A planet like Earth is composed of matter, forming a gravity well based upon the total energy content $M$.  If, over a long period, the atoms all decay into photons, all the photons will escape the gravity well to an arbitrary distance.  This would happen either one by one, as atoms randomly decay, or even if the planet were spontaneously transformed into radiation wholesale.  Why is this?  Since the total radiative energy is still $M$ and should form the same gravity well, why is the radiative energy able to escape, when the mass energy is not?

Comment: The earth can be seen from satellites, proving that light can indeed escape the earth.

Comment: Of course. But my question is the conceptual one of why matter stays bound while light does not. A planet is presumably a body of matter and energy that is gravitationally bound. But if that same amount of energy were converted to light, it has the same gravity, but not the intermolecular chemical forces. If it is the chemical forces that make the difference, that seems to contradict saying the Earth is gravitationally bound.

Comment: The one difference I can see is that light has 100% kinetic energy, while in matter form it has kinetic but also potential energy, so perhaps that energy is not "available" to allow the matter to escape the gravity well.

Comment: To prevent light from escaping you need to shrink the Earth down to its Schwarzschild radius, ~8.87 mm.

Comment: Nothing to do with General Relativity!

Comment: @m4r35n357 Sure, you don't *need* GR to adequately calculate the behaviour of light near Earth. But you do need GR to properly calculate when light can be gravitationally bound. Of course, that only happens within the photon sphere, at 1.5× the Schwarzschild radius. And we don't know any process to produce such high energy density for such a tiny radius.

Comment: @PM2Ring Both the OP and their comments are about non-relativistic concepts.  You are the only one here talking about GR ;)

Comment: I think the question is very much in the realm of GR, as in the Newtonian framework light, being massless, is not affected by gravity, nor would an amount of light produce its own gravity.

Answer (score 1):

This isn’t a distinction between mass and radiation. Indeed, if a small portion of the mass were converted to radiation but instead of escaping were used to propel matter, then the matter would escape.

The issue is more of a thermodynamic issue than a distinction between matter and radiation. Radiation escaping itself is higher entropy than radiation propelling matter to escape. Both do happen, but over long time periods the one that produces more entropy will happen more.

The other related issue is escape velocity. Whether it is matter or light, if it moves faster than the escape velocity then it will escape. Hydrogen and helium have such high velocities here on earth, so helium easily escapes the earth. Other molecules require much higher temperatures to reach escape velocity. Light, on the other hand, is at escape velocity even at low temperatures.

Comment: That's a good point. I used the very long time scale decay as a framing of the question, but my real question is probably better stated as: if you had a volume of radiation with the mass-energy of Earth, trapped by say some enormous dodecahedron of indestructible mirrors, and then suddenly deleted the mirrors, the light would all presumably escape.  My question is why does gravity trap one but not the other?

Comment: @RC_23 I added another paragraph in that topic

Answer (score 0):

Mass and energy are separate. The energy of mass is in the kinetic and potential energy and radius of its atoms orbiting electrons. According to Einstein's equation E=MCsquared, it takes 510000 ev for an electron to escape its proton. This is based on the equation's derivation where centrifugal force exceeds force to proton.
Mass doesn't decay or convert to energy, but rather its atoms lose energy through radiation to other masses.
Einstein's escape energy is supported by the need for linear accelerators or plasmas plus strong magnets to isolate electrons.
This raises many issues with conventional science.